# Unable to connect Oracle server from google cloud DataFlow

Tags: oracle, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, ojdbc

I am trying to read data from Oracle server which is running in 'CST' timezone. My google DataFlow is running in 'us-central1' region. I am using Apache Beam-2.3.0 `JDBCIO.read()` method to read data from Oracle server. I am able to connect and read data from server using '**DirectRunner**' but getting the following error in '**DataflowRunner**' using **ojdbc8** driver jar

```java
(901b8e8f2f8a547a): java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01882: timezone region not found
)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.MapTaskExecutorFactory$3.typedApply(MapTaskExecutorFactory.java:338)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.MapTaskExecutorFactory$3.typedApply(MapTaskExecutorFactory.java:308)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.graph.Networks$TypeSafeNodeFunction.apply(Networks.java:63)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.graph.Networks$TypeSafeNodeFunction.apply(Networks.java:50)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.graph.Networks.replaceDirectedNetworkNodes(Networks.java:87)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.MapTaskExecutorFactory.create(MapTaskExecutorFactory.java:154)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:308)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:264)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:133)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:113)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:100)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01882: timezone region not found
)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:36)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeSetup(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DoFnInstanceManagers$ConcurrentQueueInstanceManager.deserializeCopy(DoFnInstanceManagers.java:63)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DoFnInstanceManagers$ConcurrentQueueInstanceManager.peek(DoFnInstanceManagers.java:45)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.UserParDoFnFactory.create(UserParDoFnFactory.java:94)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DefaultParDoFnFactory.create(DefaultParDoFnFactory.java:74)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.MapTaskExecutorFactory.createParDoOperation(MapTaskExecutorFactory.java:415)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.MapTaskExecutorFactory$3.typedApply(MapTaskExecutorFactory.java:326)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01882: timezone region not found
)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2294)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2039)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1533)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadFn.setup(JdbcIO.java:503)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01882: timezone region not found

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:441)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:436)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:1061)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:550)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:499)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:1279)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:663)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:688)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:39)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:256)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2304)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2290)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2039)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1533)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadFn.setup(JdbcIO.java:503)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$ReadFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeSetup(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DoFnInstanceManagers$ConcurrentQueueInstanceManager.deserializeCopy(DoFnInstanceManagers.java:63)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DoFnInstanceManagers$ConcurrentQueueInstanceManager.peek(DoFnInstanceManagers.java:45)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.UserParDoFnFactory.create(UserParDoFnFactory.java:94)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DefaultParDoFnFactory.create(DefaultParDoFnFactory.java:74)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.MapTaskExecutorFactory.createParDoOperation(MapTaskExecutorFactory.java:415)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.MapTaskExecutorFactory$3.typedApply(MapTaskExecutorFactory.java:326)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.MapTaskExecutorFactory$3.typedApply(MapTaskExecutorFactory.java:308)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.graph.Networks$TypeSafeNodeFunction.apply(Networks.java:63)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.graph.Networks$TypeSafeNodeFunction.apply(Networks.java:50)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.graph.Networks.replaceDirectedNetworkNodes(Networks.java:87)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.MapTaskExecutorFactory.create(MapTaskExecutorFactory.java:154)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:308)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:264)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:133)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:113)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:100)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Note:** Connected and read data from server successfully using **ojdbc6** driver in both DirectRunner and DataflowRunner. But I want to get it work using **ojdbc8** driver jar.

The following is my datasourceConfiguration for JDBCIO

```java
DataSourceConfiguration dataSourceConfiguration = JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration
    .create(options.getDriverName(), options.getJdbcUrl())
    .withUsername(options.getUsername())
    .withPassword(options.getPassword())
    .withConnectionProperties("timezone=CST");
```

Any inputs to make this connection successfull using **ojdbc8** driver jar in '**DataflowRunner**'?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the error `(ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01882: timezone region not found` is known and quite common with the Oracle JDBC drivers.

It happens when the the JDBC driver is not able, for some reason, to send the right Timezone ID to the server. After some investigation and searches across different sources (including other Stack Overflow cases such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452513/how-to-set-the-timezone-region-for-jdbc-connection-and-avoid-the-sqlexception-ti) or [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156379/ora-01882-timezone-region-not-found)), I have found different possible solutions, so let me summarize them here:

- Make sure that you are using the latest available version of the *ojdbc8* driver, because maybe there was something broken in the specific version you were using. Try to change to a different version and see if that works.
- Try setting the default Timezone to your timezone before establishing the connection, as in *Solution 2* below.
- Add the configuration line in *Solution 3* to the file `oracle/jdbc/defaultConnectionProperties.properties`.

Summarized solutions:

```
// Solution 2
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("yourTimeZone");
TimeZone.setDefault(timeZone);

// Solution 3
oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false
```