# ORA-01882: timezone region not found error not letting establish connection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

While trying to connect to db2, using ojdbc8, I am getting an error:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL
> level 1 ORA-01882: timezone region not found
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:509)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:456)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:451)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:1040)  at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:552)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:550)  at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:268)  at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:501)
> at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:1292)
> at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:1025)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)  at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:793)
> at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:57)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:747)  at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:562)  at
> java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)  at
> java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)  at
> com.Learnjdbc.Connect.getConnection(Connect.java:33)

As per the line in logs, I am getting error on below line

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,username,password);
```

Code snippet:

```
       try {
                Class.forName(className);
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL,username,password);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

There is one way mentioned in [ORA-01882: timezone region not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156379/ora-01882-timezone-region-not-found) but this talks about changes in JAR, while I am using maven repo to get packages.

Comment: What's the version of database?

Comment: Attempting to connect to DB2 using the Oracle JDBC driver makes no sense at all. DB2 is an entirely different product than Oracle. Given the error, I'm assuming you're actually connecting to Oracle, and have removed the db2 tag. Please provide a [mre], including your exact server version, driver version and connection URL. (and no, ojdbc8 is not a version number, it just means the driver is for Java 8).

Comment: What is your time zone? You may set it with Environment variable like this: `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Duser.timezone=Europe/Zurich`

Comment: Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452513/how-to-set-the-timezone-region-for-jdbc-connection-and-avoid-the-sqlexception-ti).